# How to call a procedure after finish the Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task

How I can aware of a Task finished ?I want a thing like `RunWorkerCompleted` event in `BackGroundWorker`.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ContinueWhenAll`, So you will be *notified* when all processes finished.

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(myTasks, _ => OnAllTasksFinished());

private void OnAllTasksFinished()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Finished!");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am calling multithread method from task(in the end)

Pattern multithrea method:

```
private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MethodInvoker method = delegate
    {
        uiSomeTextBox.Text = "some text";
    };

if (InvokeRequired)
    BeginInvoke(method);
else
    method.Invoke();
```

}

You can safe work with WFA like in bacroundWorker

When algorithm in BackGrounWorker come to return, he generate event about end of work. But thread object can still continue to exist. It's inner singularity Windows and CLR, - Threads that may exist for some time after death.

Comment: :In what line of this code you can aware thta your job finishes?

Comment: I am call in the end of Task method, it's not so good because task still can be work, but I don't found any other way.

Comment: If I correctly understand you need to thread safe work when your Yask is ower.

Comment: If you just need to know when thread is destoyed, you can check it by IsCompleted property.

Comment: You mean isn't a way that when a thread finish it's work call a callback function?So how BackGroundWorker works?It's not a good way that I check IsCompleted properties periodically

Comment: When algorithm in BackGrounWorker come to return, he generate event about end of work. But thread object can still continue to exist. It's inner singularity Windows and CLR, - Threads that may exist for some time after death.